# how do I solve the error : bad class file?

Tags: javafx

I am facing an error. I am very new to javafx.
when i created a new javafx project in intellij , the import statements and every "javafx" word was red as the ide didnt recognised the word as a keyword , i got an issue that said
"cannot resolve symbol javafx", "javafx.Application does not exist".
i searched on youtube and followed the instructions of this guy:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b60Fl2WLaQY

All errors got solved but when i tried to run the pre-written code which intellij produces , i got the following error:

"java: cannot access javafx.application.Application
bad class file: /C:/Users/priyanshu nautiyal/javafx-sdk-
11.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar!/javafx/application/Application.class
class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 51.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath."

does someone know how to solve it?

Comment: What version of the JDK do you have installed? Which JDK have you configured IntelliJ to use?

Comment: @Slaw I have jdk 1.7.0 installed,  i have configured intellij to use jdk 1.7

Comment: There's your problem. JavaFX 11-16 requires Java 11+. Why are you using Java 7? That's a really outdated version. At the very least you should use Java 8 (and JavaFX 8). But note the latest version of Java is 16.0.2 and the latest version of JavaFX is 16.